# How to trigger Jquery slide effect only when a specific option is selected and button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, slide

I have a simple form with a  dropdown, an input zipcode field, and a button. I want the Jquery slide effect that I have created to execute only when 1. A specific  is selected, 2. When a zip code is entered and 3. when the button is clicked to submit. The button only works after I execute other JS on the page, and I cannot get the if statement to work properly. Please help.

These effect are working correctly and doing what I want. I just need them to trigger when the above criteria is met:

```
$( "#slide-2" ).show("slide", {direction: "right"}, 500);
$( "#slide-1" ).hide("slide", {direction: "left"}, 500);

<form class="product-form">
    <select id="product-dropdown">
<option value="">Select a Product</option>
      <option value="auto" selected>Auto Insurance</option>
<option value="autoresidence" id="bundled-selected">Auto + Residence (save more!)</option>
      <option value="home">Home Insurance</option>
      <option value="home-condo">Condo Insurance</option>
      <option value="renters">Renters Insurance</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" class="quote-zip" id="gaq-zip-code" name="gaqZipCode" placeholder="Enter Zip Code" maxlength="5">

      <button href="#" id="submit-gaq" class="quote-submit">Get a Quote</button>
</form>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $( ".quote-submit" ).click(function() {
   $( "#slide-2" ).show("slide", {direction: "right"}, 500);
   $( "#slide-1" ).hide("slide", {direction: "left"}, 500);
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: `"1. A specific is selected"` - a specific what and where?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend following the pattern that you already have in order to trigger the fewest events -- on the button click, verify the other criteria.

```
$(".quote-submit").click(function () {
    if ($("#product-dropdown").val() == "Specific Text" && $("gaq-zip-code").val().length == 5) {
        $("#slide-2").show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 500);
        $("#slide-1").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Following your requirements, also added ability to disable the button. You don't want people wondering why the form isn't submitting even though it should be obvious.

```
if ($('#gaq-zip-code').val().length == 0 && ($("#product-dropdown").val() == "Home Insurance")) {
   $('submit-gaq').removeAttr('disabled');
   $( ".quote-submit" ).click(function() {
   $( "#slide-2" ).show("slide", {direction: "right"}, 500);
   $( "#slide-1" ).hide("slide", {direction: "left"}, 500);
    });
}
else{
$('submit-gaq').attr('disabled','disabled'); 
}
```